# How to explicitly set namespace of a node in json-ld

Tags: json-ld

I define a jsonld file with multiple context. Each context define a term with the same name. When a compact is done on the jsonld file, all field with the same name are in the same namespace.

For example, with the folowing file

```
{
    "@context": [
    {
        "name1": "http://example.org/name1/",

        "id" : {
            "@id" : "name:id",
            "@type" : "xsd:string"
        }

    },
    {
        "name2": "http://example.org/name2/",
        "identifier": {
            "@id": "name2"
        },
        "id" : {
            "@id" : "name2:id",
            "@type" : "xsd:string"
        }

    }],
    "@id": "http://example.org/1",
    "id" : "id/1",
    "identifier": {
        "id" : "identifier/1"
    }
}
```

I obtain this result after compaction

```
{
  "@id" : "http://example.org/1",
  "http://example.org/name2/" : {
    "http://example.org/name2/id" : {
      "@type" : "xsd:string",
      "@value" : "identifier/1"
    }
  },
  "http://example.org/name2/id" : {
    "@type" : "xsd:string",
    "@value" : "id/1"
  }
}
```

But I will expect this

```
{
  "@id" : "http://example.org/1",
  "http://example.org/name2/" : {
    "http://example.org/name2/id" : {
      "@type" : "xsd:string",
      "@value" : "identifier/1"
    }
  },
  "http://example.org/name1/id" : {  <== here name1
    "@type" : "xsd:string",
    "@value" : "id/1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Terms defined in contexts are taken in order, with the last context encountered winning. In this example, I don't see any way to use a different term when compacting. However, you may want to see [Scoped Contexts](https://json-ld.org/spec/latest/json-ld/#scoped-contexts) in JSON-LD 1.1 that does provide you more flexibility.

Comment: even with sub context and vocabulary extended, the id is not in the right namespace.

`{
 "@context": [
 {
  "name1": "http://example.org/name1/",
  
  "id" : {
   "@id" : "name1:id",
   "@type" : "xsd:string"
  },
  
  "identifier": {
   "@id": "http://example.org/identifier/",
   "id" : {
    "@id" : "http://example.org/identifier/id",
    "@type" : "xsd:string",
    "@context" : {
     "@vocab" : "http://example.org/identifier/"
    }
   }
  }
  
 }],
 "@id": "http://example.org/1",
 "id" : "id/1",
 "identifier": {
  "id" : "identifier/1"
 }
}
`